# validate fields from diffrent models in a single form

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have the form 
TblRegistration/_form.php

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'tbl-registration-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>


 <?php echo $form->errorSummary(array($model,$model1)); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'director'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'director',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'director'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'experience'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'experience'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'experience'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'language'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'language',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'language'); ?>
    </div>
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model1,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model1,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model1,'email'); ?>
    </div>
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model1,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model1,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model1,'password'); ?>
    </div>




    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

My actioncreate  create contain

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new TblRegistration;
        $model1=new TblLogin();

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        //$this->performAjaxValidation($model1);

        if(isset($_POST['TblRegistration']) && isset($_POST['TblLogin']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['TblRegistration'];
                        $model1->attributes=$_POST['TblLogin'];
            $model->save();
            if($model->save())
            {

                    $model1->reg_id=$model->reg_id;

                    $model1->save();
            }
            if(($model->save() )&& ($model1->save()))
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->reg_id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

**my fields email and password is from the model TblLogin.I want to validate those fields before iam saving the data.how can i achive this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After:

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['TblRegistration'];
$model1->attributes=$_POST['TblLogin'];
```

Add:

```
if($model->validate() && $model1->validate()){
$model->save();
...
```

Comment: i think it wil check whether  the validation occurs or not,but i want to print the validation message of $model1 elements in $models form.

Comment: Right, so if it doesn't validate, you then want to render the registration view again, but don't pass empty models to it, pass the current model, because when validation is done, if it fails it adds errors to the model. These will display on your form.

Comment: validation message for first model $model is printed successfully,but second model $model1 validation is not working.

Comment: well, looking at your code above, you only appear to be passing $model to the create view, you must pass both models. So your render code must look something like this $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model,'model1'=>$model1));

Comment: If this helped, feel free to select this as an answer

Comment: No worries mate, Yii took me a while to get my head around, but once you do it's really nice.

Comment: can u explain how can i display my view page with enterd data,ie data from two models Login and register?for me its showing that email and password not set